# How to remove duplicate values compare two array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array.

one

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [driverId] => 3
            [latitude] => 23.752182
            [longitude] => 90.377730
            [distance] => 0
            [EstTime] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [driverId] => 6
            [latitude] => 23.752782
            [longitude] => 90.375730
            [distance] => 0.2341134331552646
            [EstTime] => 133
        )

)
```

two

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [driverId] => 3
        )
     [1] => Array
        (
            [driverId] => 61

        )


)
```

first array store in `$info` and second array store in `$infor`

here first array item driverId is 3 and second array item driverId is 3.

so in my output i want to skip first array first item.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

When looping through each array store the driverId in another array and also check that the current driverId is not in this array, if it is then we can skip it. For example:

```
    $ids = array();

    foreach($infor AS $arr2){
        $ids[] = $arr2['driverId'];
    }

    foreach($info AS $i){
        if(!in_array($i['driverId'],$ids)){
            print_r($i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @smistry Spent 5 hours with trying to solve something simple as this, tried using array_diff, array_intersect, and even tried nested foreach loop to no avail, but your example put me in the right direction, thanks.